# Ignore Null Indices in Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, player.io

I have an array that forms values based on index. Here's an example:

```
{0: [
0: [
0: 2
], 
1: <null>, 
2: <null>, 
3: 5}
```

The array, actually considered an object (Because it's a DatabaseObject from PlayerIO's BigDB), is converted to a string and displayed in a DisplayGridView. You can copy the cell and it will display all the indices and values, including the nulls. Normally, this isn't a problem, but if the index is, say, 1,205,493, this leads to some very serious memory issues. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Search term "sparse array"... Can you comment on why don't you use `Dictionary<int,Whatever>`?

Comment: Oh, I should've specified. It's made by a function that returns a generic object. Using .GetType() on it gives "PlayerIOClient.Internal.identifier467".